# Launch & monitor Spring Batch jobs (deployed to Jboss EAP) via shell scripts

Tags: shell, jboss, spring-batch, scheduler, java-batch

**Scenarios**

- All batch applications (Spring Batch based) have to deploy to Jboss EAP.
- All batch jobs have to be launched & monitored by using the existing enterprise workload/scheduling system, e.g. ASG-Zena via shell scripts.
- All batch jobs will have HTTP endpoints for start job, get state of the job, and stop job. The shell scripts will make use of the endpoints to control the batch jobs.

  - All batch jobs will be launched asynchronously
- The shell script will return an exit code to indicate the execution result of the batch job so the enterprise scheduler system can track the success or failure of the batch jobs

[Enterprise Workload/Scheduling][Shell Scripts] <--> [HTTP][[Batch Applications] Jboss EAP]

**Questions**

1. As the batch jobs are launched asynchronously via HTTP endpoint, how can the shell script get the execution result of the batch job?

Answer (score 1):

Your shell script will need to poll for the results.  The script kicks off the job, then polls for the result.